# Set state for dynamically generated component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, combobox, programmatically-created

I'm reusing a couple of external components to create my custom Combobox in strapi app.
Values are received from server so I need to add options dynamically.
Currently there is the following code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Combobox,
  ComboboxOption
} from "@strapi/design-system";

export default function ComboboxCustom({
  valuesList,
  valueSelected
}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const combo = (<Combobox label="Country" value={value} onChange={setValue}>
    {valuesList.map((entry) => {
      return(
        <ComboboxOption value="{entry.id}">{entry.name}</ComboboxOption>
      );
    })}
  </Combobox>);
  // setValue(valueSelected)
  return combo;
}
```

And everything goes good until I try so set 'selected' option basing on another set of data. In static world I could just say `useState(valueSelected)` and it will work. But as code generated dynamically, there is no related option yet, so I get failure like "Failed to get 'props' property of undefined".

I tried to put this combobox into a variable and set state between creation and returning it (commented `setValue` line before the return statement) but then app gets in a loop and returns "Too many re-renders".

Does anyone has an idea of how to change/rewrite this to be able to set selected value for dynamically created combobox?

Answer (score 1):

So I assume that the values are dynamically fetched and passed to the ComboboxCustom.
I think you can add setValue(valueSelected) inside an useEffect.
onChange of the prop valueSelected.something like,

useEffect(() => {

```
   setValue(valueSelected)

}, [valueSelected])
```

Also handle the return when the value is not yet loaded. like before doing valuesList.map, first check if valueList ? (render actual) : (render empty)

Hope this helps!!

Thanks,
Anu

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. Basing on your suggestion I made my code work and found also alternative solution. Pasted it as another answer as comments are unlikely give to post so long text and format code well.
Please take a look and feel free to comment if something could or should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got working solution based on answer from @Anu.
Cause `valuesList` is got as GET-request from another hook, I have to check values are already present (first hook hit gives `[]` yet) and bind Combobox state updating to change of `valuesList` also. Though I don't fell like this solution is perfect.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Combobox,
  ComboboxOption
} from "@strapi/design-system";

export default function ComboboxCustom({
  valuesList,
  valueSelected,
}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  let combo = null;
  useEffect(() => {
    if(combo && combo?.props?.children?.length > 0 && valuesList.length > 0) {
      setValue(valueSelected)
    }
 }, [valueSelected, valuesList])

  combo = (<Combobox label="Country" value={value?.toString()} onChange={setValue}>
    {valuesList.map((entry) => {
      return(
        <ComboboxOption value={entry?.id?.toString()}>{entry.name}</ComboboxOption>
      );
    })}
  </Combobox>);
  return combo;
}
```

After that I decided avoid creating custom component based on already published as I'll need to add and process event listeners that are added for us in the existing components. So I placed this code directly into my modal and it also works:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
const [deliveryCountryValue, setDeliveryCountryValue] = useState('');

useEffect(async () => {
  const countriesReceived = await countryRequests.getAllCountries();
  setCountries(countriesReceived);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // If there is no selected value yet, set the one we get from order from server
  const valueDelivery = deliveryCountryValue != '' ? deliveryCountryValue : order.country?.id;
  if(countries.length > 0) {
    setDeliveryCountryValue(valueDelivery);
    order.country = countries.find(x => x.id == valueDelivery);
  }
}, [deliveryCountryValue, countries])


<Combobox key='delivery-combo' label="Country" value={deliveryCountryValue?.toString()} onChange={setDeliveryCountryValue}>
  {countries.map((entry) => {
   return(
      <ComboboxOption key={'delivery'+entry.id} value={entry?.id?.toString()}>{entry.name}</ComboboxOption>
    );
  })}
</Combobox>
```